# Firebase React/Redux multipath updates from array

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I have an array of objects that I need to push to firebase. Each object should have its own push key. The only way I have been able to accomplish this is by map over the array and passing each object to a redux action that handles the individual object push. I know this not the best way to do this and was wondering how else this can be accomplished?

When I try to pass the array to the action (to build an update object to pass to firebase.database().ref().update()) I get an error saying that it can only accept plain objects. Does the array need to be converted to an object.

```js
const arr = [{0: "x", 1:"y"}, {0:"a", 1: "b"}]
this.props.action(arr)// throws error "Actions must be plain objects"
```

Is this not possible? Should I be using Promises instead?

I'm sure there is an answer to this but I can't find it so any direction would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Below are the screenshots for the firebase data and my array data

[Firebase Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/av5ME.png)
[Array Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUvyz.png)

Comment: Post your Firebase data structure and the structure of the data you're trying to update. You're correct that you can't update Firebase with only a plain array - the realtime database is basically a big JSON object tree. However, you *can* update the database all at once using a single object. The object needs to be structured the same as your Firebase database, containing only the keys and data you want to update. Firebase will do the work of merging them when you update the ref.

Comment: just added the screenshots! thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you trying to add new entries, or update the existing ones? What is the relevance of the keys of the entries under "markets", -Kx_r3... and -KxcWq...?

Comment: i am adding new entries. the reason for the keys is because i need to later fetch them and add specific markets (user selected) to other collections

Comment: sorry I just realized I took the wrong screenshot - updating now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out.

```js
//action (passed attendingMarkets array)
export const vendorTest = (vendorUid, attendingMarkets) => {
 var updates = {};

 attendingMarkets.map((map, idx) => {
  const date = map.date;
  const market = map.market;
  var newMarketKey = firebase
   .database()
   .ref()
   .child("/vendors/" + vendorUid + "/markets")
   .push().key;
  updates["/vendors/" + vendorUid + "/markets/" + newMarketKey] = {
   date,
   market
  };
 });
 return dispatch => {
  firebase
   .database()
   .ref()
   .update(updates)
   .then(() => {
    dispatch({ type: VENDOR_ADD_MARKETS });
   });
 };
};
```